# LINQ to SQL ambiguous 'IsolationLevel' between 'System.Data.IsolationLevel' and 'System.Transactions.IsolationLevel'

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a SQL statement with a bunch of NOLOCKs in it.  After doing some research I came across a way to deal with this in LINQ to SQL.  Here is how I did it:

```
int year = 2011;
int quarter = 4;

DateTime timeframe = new DateTime(year, (quarter * 3), 01).AddMonths(1); 


using (var txn = new TransactionScope(
    TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
    new TransactionOptions
    {
        IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
    }))
{
    // Your LINQ to SQL query goes here
    var results =

        from wo in WORKORDERs

            join wot in WORKORDERTYPEs on wo.Wot_oi equals wot.Wotyoi

            join pri in PRIORITies on wo.Prio_oi equals pri.Priooi

            join s in SITEs on wo.BEparn_oi equals s.Siteoi

        where wo.Audt_created_dttm.Value.Year >= year - 3 && wo.Audt_created_dttm.Value.Year >= 2006    
            && wo.Audt_created_dttm < timeframe && (s.Id =="NM" || s.Id == "TH") && 
            (!wot.Id.Contains("stand") && wo.Ci_cnc_date != null && pri.Prioid != "1 - Routine") &&
            (pri.Prioid.Contains("1") || pri.Prioid.Contains("2") || pri.Prioid.Contains("3"))

        select new {PM = wo.Wosource, Site = s.Id, Priority = pri.Prioid, Worktype = wot.Id,
            WoNumber = wo.Id, Description = wo.Aenm, CreateDate = wo.Audt_created_dttm, 
            CloseDate = wo.Clsdt_date, Planning = 
                (pri.Prioid == "1 - Routine" || pri.Prioid == "6 - Planned Outage") ? "Planned" : "Unplanned"}; 
}
```

The problem is that I receive this error and can find no information on it.

```
'IsolationLevel' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Data.IsolationLevel' and 'System.Transactions.IsolationLevel'

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.IsolationLevel' to 'System.Transactions.IsolationLevel'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: You do know that you can fully qualify type names?

Comment: @ Kirk Woll:  Not really.  I didn't even know that's what it was looking for.  it worked though.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like this code:

```
new TransactionOptions
{
    IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
}
```

should be:

```
new TransactionOptions
{
    IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I were to guess, you have a `using` statement for both `System.Data` and `System.Transactions`. The problem is that there is a type called IsolationLevel in both of those, and the compiler doesn't know which one to use. Either remove the System.Data reference, or do

```
new TransactionOptions
{
    IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
}
```